# Проблема с добавлением std::condition_variable.wait() для второй std::condition_variable

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Если я добавляю в функцию wait для другой переменной после notfy_one для первой cv, первая перестает получать уведомление.

Здесь работает

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

struct user{
    std::unique_ptr<std::mutex> recv_mu;
    std::unique_ptr<std::condition_variable> recv_cv;
    std::unique_ptr<std::mutex> send_mu;
    std::unique_ptr<std::condition_variable> send_cv;
    std::string str_data;
    bool shut_down{};
};

std::condition_variable cv1;
std::mutex mu;

std::map<std::string, user> users;

void TCPRecvThread() {
    std::cout << "\nrecvThread started";
    std::mutex* recv_mu = users["biba"].recv_mu.get();
    std::condition_variable* recv_cv = users["biba"].recv_cv.get();

    std::mutex* send_mu = users["biba"].send_mu.get();
    std::condition_variable* send_cv = users["biba"].send_cv.get();

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> send_lk(*send_mu);

    send_lk.unlock();
    send_cv->notify_one();
    send_lk.lock();

    std::cout << "\nnotified sendThread";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> recv_lk(*recv_mu);
    //recv_cv->wait(recv_lk);  проблема здесь
} 

void TCPSendThread() {
    std::cout << "\nsendThread started";

    std::mutex* send_mu = users["biba"].send_mu.get();
    std::condition_variable* send_cv = users["biba"].send_cv.get();

    std::mutex* recv_mu = users["biba"].recv_mu.get();
    std::condition_variable* recv_cv = users["biba"].recv_cv.get();

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> send_lk(*send_mu);
    std::cout << "\nwaiting for notify";
    send_cv->wait(send_lk);

    std::cout << "\nrecieved a notify from recvThread";
}

int main() {
    std::string str = "";
    users["biba"] = { std::make_unique<std::mutex>(), std::make_unique<std::condition_variable>(), std::make_unique<std::mutex>(), std::make_unique<std::condition_variable>(), str, false };

    std::thread send_th(TCPSendThread); 
    send_th.detach();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    std::thread recv_th(TCPRecvThread);
    recv_th.detach();

    while (true) {
    }

    return 0;
}
```

А здесь нет

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

struct user{
    std::unique_ptr<std::mutex> recv_mu;
    std::unique_ptr<std::condition_variable> recv_cv;
    std::unique_ptr<std::mutex> send_mu;
    std::unique_ptr<std::condition_variable> send_cv;
    std::string str_data;
    bool shut_down{};
};

std::condition_variable cv1;
std::mutex mu;

std::map<std::string, user> users;

void TCPRecvThread() {
    std::cout << "\nrecvThread started";
    std::mutex* recv_mu = users["biba"].recv_mu.get();
    std::condition_variable* recv_cv = users["biba"].recv_cv.get();

    std::mutex* send_mu = users["biba"].send_mu.get();
    std::condition_variable* send_cv = users["biba"].send_cv.get();

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> send_lk(*send_mu);

    send_lk.unlock();
    send_cv->notify_one();
    send_lk.lock();

    std::cout << "\nnotified sendThread";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> recv_lk(*recv_mu);
    recv_cv->wait(recv_lk);  //проблема здесь
} 

void TCPSendThread() {
    std::cout << "\nsendThread started";

    std::mutex* send_mu = users["biba"].send_mu.get();
    std::condition_variable* send_cv = users["biba"].send_cv.get();

    std::mutex* recv_mu = users["biba"].recv_mu.get();
    std::condition_variable* recv_cv = users["biba"].recv_cv.get();

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> send_lk(*send_mu);
    std::cout << "\nwaiting for notify";
    send_cv->wait(send_lk);

    std::cout << "\nrecieved a notify from recvThread";
}

int main() {
    std::string str = "";
    users["biba"] = { std::make_unique<std::mutex>(), std::make_unique<std::condition_variable>(), std::make_unique<std::mutex>(), std::make_unique<std::condition_variable>(), str, false };

    std::thread send_th(TCPSendThread); 
    send_th.detach();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    std::thread recv_th(TCPRecvThread);
    recv_th.detach();

    while (true) {
    }

    return 0;
}
```

В чем здесь может быть проблема?

**UPD**

В моем случае помогло удаление `std::unique_lock<std::mutex> send_lk(*send_mu)` и всех последующих операций с ним из функции `TCPRecvThread()`. Как `send_lk.unlock()` и `send_lk.lock()` соответственно до и после `send_cv->notify_one()` могли повлиять на `send_cv->wait()`?

Comment: В функции `TCPRecvThread()` последней командой вы ждёте сигнал `recv_cv->wait(recv_lk);`, а его никто не посылает, вот и ждёте. Поток главный в бесконечном цикле `while (true)`, а первый `TCPSendThread()` уже закрылся  и умер.

Comment: @AlexGlebe Да, это так, но `TCPSendThread()` в первом случае выдает сообщение и завершает свою работу, а во втором нет. Даже после того как я добавил в в код `TCPSendThread()` посыл сигнала `recv_cv`, код всё так же не выполняется дальше `send_cv->wait(send_lk)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замочек `sendmu` установленный вручную в `TCPRecvThread()` не даёт процессу `TCPSendThread()` взять этот замок себе.

```
TCPRecvThread()         TCPSendThread()
                        lock sendmu
                        wait , unlock sendmu
lock sendmu
unlock sendmu
notify_one              не успеваю залочить sendmu ...
lock sendmu            
lock recv_mu
wait , unlock recv_mu
                        чтобы очнуться, надо залочить
                        sendmu для себя, а он вечно заперт
```

После `notify_one` вы сразу-же залочили `sendmu`. Не хватило времени, чтобы другой процесс взял `sendmu` себе. Можно после `notify_one` добавить паузу чтобы сразу не лочить `sendmu`. Или даже просто его не закрывать второй раз.